# ConTeXt: How to display last page number (Page # of #) in header/footer?

Tags: header-footer, tex-core, context, page-numbering, lastpage

In LaTeX, I could do something like:

```
\fancyhead[R]{\HeaderFont{\thepage{}/\pageref{LastPage}}}
```

and/or

```
\fancyfoot[R]{\FooterFont{\thepage{}/\pageref{LastPage}}}
```

How to achieve the same with ConTeXt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nailed it:

```
\setupheadertexts[Page \currentpage\ of \lastpage]
```

and/or

```
\setupfootertexts[Page \currentpage\ of \lastpage]
```

The simplicity of ConTeXt rocks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to respect `\definestructureconversionset[]`